# Corrupt file finder

Tags: windows, search

I have a TON of data recovered from a formatted disk and I need to filter out the files that have been partially overwritten and, therefore, are unreadable and useless.

Comment: What OS must be supported? Which file types must be recognized?

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, I forgot to put that in. Windows 7+ and any user data (images, videos, audio, documents, etc).

Comment: OK. Windows is not my environment (except those for light and fresh air), so I cannot really recommend anything. While waiting for answers, you might wish to take a look at [Find all corrupted files and folders on the hard drive](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/86-find-all-corrupted-files-and-folders-on-the-hard-drive) – and [other results from my quick Google-Fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+corrupt-file-finder).

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I did some searching with Google and DuckDuckGo but all I found was either corrupt file finders for very specific types of files (PDFs, JPGs, etc) or resolving corrupt Windows files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to find any such tool. the internal data structures **in** the files are corrupt, and only software that knows how the data is supposed to be organized, is able to find errors. The programs that they weer intended for are you best bet, especially because these often allow for minor variations and errors in the files.

Comment: That would change your question to: *How can I quickly check if my recovered XLS files (etc) are intact/corrupt?*, which is an off-topic question here, and should be placed on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) I suggest you do that for the bulk of your file types *by type*.

Comment: www.officerecovery.com has a bunch of file repair recovery tools.  The good new they generally just work. The bad news is they are individual products and expensive.

Answer (score -1):

I also found the link suggested by @Izzy in the comments.

[Article from mysysadmintips.com](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/86-find-all-corrupted-files-and-folders-on-the-hard-drive)

This article suggests using the program Robocopy to perform a copy of the folder where your corrupted files are and it will copy all the files that are not corrupted and provide a list in the log of all the files that it skipped.

Here is the exact command they recommend:

`robocopy "D:" "E:" /E /COPYALL /R:0 /TEE /LOG:"C:\robo-log.txt"`

"D:" - Source

"E:" - Destination

/E - copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.

/COPYALL - copy all file info

/R:0 - number of retries - 0. (Skips corrupted files instead of constantly retrying).

/TEE - output to console window, as well as the log file.

/LOG:"C:\robo-log.txt" - path to the log file.

Comment: Is there a `robocopy` command to only log corrupted files as I don't want to duplicate the healthy data? Thanks.

Comment: A comment I saw on that website said that unless the process actually copies the files it only looks at the file index so does not detect corruption.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. No files were skipped or failed but plenty were corrupted. Also, the command should be `robocopy "D:" "E:" /E /COPYALL /R:0 /TEE /LOG:"C:\robo-log.txt"` - there was a space between `/` and `COPYALL` which threw an `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/"` error.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP has files *that were recovered*, i.e. their organization in the file structure is correct and their disk sectors are OK. So RoboCopy will not find any errors. It's the internal data structures **in** the files that are corrupt.